# PDO Fatal error on Bluemix

Tags: php, pdo, ibm-cloud

I'm really stuck in making PDO working with PHP in bluemix.
I can't use it, everytime I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in ...
```

Then i've added the options.json under .bp-config\

```
{
     "PHP_VERSION": "{PHP_55_LATEST}",
       "WEB_SERVER": "httpd",
     "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [ "bz2", "zlib", "openssl", "fpm", "tokenizer", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "pdo", "mysqli"]
}
```

then i've also tried with the php.ini under .bp-config\

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=mbstring.so
```

and after a phpinfo(); I get:

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/tmp/staged/app/php' '--disable-static' '--enable-shared' '--enable-ftp=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--enable-soap=shared' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-zip=shared' '--with-bz2=shared' '--with-curl=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-cdb' '--with-gdbm' '--with-mcrypt=shared' '--with-mhash=shared' '--with-mysql=shared' '--with-mysqli=shared' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-gd=shared' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--with-pspell=shared' '--with-gettext=shared' '--with-gmp=shared' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-zlib=shared' '--with-xsl=shared' '--with-snmp=shared' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-exif=shared' '--with-openssl=shared' '--enable-fpm'
```

I've also tried the composer.json:

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mysqli": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*"
  }
}
```

But still, after all this steps, i'm still getting the same error since days and days :( :desperate:

Comment: Can you share the command you used to push the application to Bluemix?

Comment: I used: `cf push PROJECTNAME` and the manifest:`[...] disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: php_buildpack
  path: .
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G`

Comment: I tried it with successful results with just the composer.json. Are you able to share your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me the composer was not working but the options.json was.

File options.json under .bp-config/ should contain also the driver you want to use. Otherwise the PDO itself is not able to communicate with DB.

This is my working options.json

```
{
"PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["bz2", "pdo", "zlib", "curl", "mcrypt", "mbstring", "mysqli", "gd", "zip", "pdo_mysql", "pdo_sqlite" ]
}
```

From your provided phpinfo() you are able to communicate to mysql, sqlite and pgsql using PDO.

To see if you have loaded driver run phpinfo() and look for section PDO. There should be something like this: `PDO drivers  mysql, sqlite` .

Answer (score 1):

just tried to replicate your problem but using composer.json as for your pasted config, it worked fine.
Probably your problem could be related to a conflict between different configurations used to solve the error.
My suggestion to solve your problem is to start from the starter code again, be sure that the MySQL service is binded correctly, and then replace the code with your one and configure composer.json with the libs you need.
Then push it again, leaving it complete all staging activities (really important!)
Let us know if you manage to solve it.